# How to refresh Listview MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

ViewModel:

```
public DataView List { get { return _list; } set { _list = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange("List"); } }
         <...>
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["X"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employees", connection);
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
                List = dt.DefaultView;
```

XAML:

```
 <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
        <ListView.DataContext>
            <local:TestViewModel/>
        </ListView.DataContext>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Login}" Header="Name" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=password}" Header="Password" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Permission}" Header="Permission" Width="110"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=locked_account}" Header="Is account locked" Width="150"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

My command:

```
  List.Delete(2);
```

The command above seem to work, however, I'm unable to see the changes in real time so how I'm supposed to refresh the listview/dataview?.

Comment: no repro - DataView work just fine. you are probably have 2 instances of local:TestViewModel

Comment: So my code is supposed to make the delete show in real time?

Answer (score 1):

Use observableCollection for this purpose. 
In your case the List variable should be `ObservableCollection<YourObject>`
See this link for more information. 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/